# How to use CSS filters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, filter

I would like to use CSS filters in JavaScript.

Example of CSS filters:

```
.filter {
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px); /* Blur filter */
    -webkit-filter: invert(1); /* Invert filter */
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(100deg); /* Rotate Hue */
    ...
}
```

For example, how can I make a blurred image using JavaScript?

```
<img id="image" onmouseover="ImageHover();" src="source.png"/>
```

while

```
function ImageHover() {
    document.getElementById('image').??????='???'
}
```

I hope you guys understand what I want.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: No, I'm not using jQuery.

Comment: In addition to Ahmed's answer I'd strong advise against inline scripting whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using **this** so the function can be used with any element/Img you want later

```
<img id="image" onmouseover="ImageHover(this);" src="source.png"/>

function ImageHover(el){
    el.classList.add("filter");
};
```

Comment: you didn't declare the handler of **onmouseout** ,, so nothing goes back to it's normal state

Comment: yes I know, but the function doesnt blur the image, or you see the blur of image?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kn9h02a5/1/
the problem was that you added the class like the way you added an inline style ,, I've fixed this by addung new css rule and added the class to the class list of that element

Comment: Thank you :) Just exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give use to that element's property, as such:

```
var image = document.getElementById('image');
image.style.webkitFilter = "blur(20px);";
```

or

```
image.style["-webkit-filter"] = "blur(20px);";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var photo = document.getElementById('yourId');

function sepia(){
    photo.style.filter = "sepia(100%)";
}
```